# Trouble on loading classes when "side effect" metaprogramming is implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, metaprogramming

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3-p125. The scenario is the following:

I implemented a `acts_as_customizable` plugin and I have an `Article` model class "acting as customizable". The plugin, through metaprogramming, *adds a method* named `customize` to a `Comment` model class (*note*: since that, the plugin has side effects because manipulate the `Comment` object outside the scope of the `Article` object).

Given that scenario, when I (re-)start the server and I run `@comment.customize` then I get the error `NoMethodError - undefined method 'customize' for #<Comment:0x0...>`. However, when I (re-)start the server and I run the following code then all works as expected:

```
Article
@comment.customize
```

If I understood the "evil" part, the above code works because the "simple" call to the `Article` class *before* to run the `customize` method makes it to fire the `acts_as_customizable` method which in turn adds (through metaprogramming) the `customize` method to the `Comment` class.

How should I avoid the "evil"?

Comment: The simple haphazard solution is to add **require_dependency 'article'** to the top of comment.rb file. However, why do you define acts_as_customizable on Article if it customizes Comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by lazy/auto loading. To save time rails doesn't load all classes on startup. Instead, it loads them when necessary. If you never access `Article`, it's not loaded and, therefore, `Comment` is not getting its dynamic methods.

> How should I avoid the "evil"?

Simple answer: use `require_dependency` (thanks, @cryo28)

Correct answer: don't do evil. Make plugin behaviour more predictable / less confusing. If it's applied to `Article`, it should act on `Article` and not `Comment`.

Comment: How could I make the "plugin behaviour more predictable" by keeping the same behavior as that I have currently implemented? That is, there is (and, if so, what is) an alternative way to avoid the "evil" in my case?

Comment: The behaviour itself is confusing. Change it. If that's not an option, use `require_dependency` to force load order.

Comment: Where I can find some example on using `require_dependency`?