# How to refactoring when metaprogramming has side effects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, metaprogramming

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3-p125. After my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827547/trouble-on-loading-classes-when-side-effect-metaprogramming-is-implemented) I ended up that I have an issue on metaprogramming a self-implemented `acts_as_customizable` plugin since the related code has *side effects* on other classes than that "acting as customizable".

To summarize the issue: the `acts_as_customizable` method stated for an `Article` model "internally" (through metaprogramming) adds a `customize` method to a `Comment` model and, in order to save time, Rails doesn't load all those classes on startup making the application to raise a `NoMethodError - undefined method 'customize' for #<Comment:0x0...>` *until* the `Article` class is loaded.

A proposed solution was to `require_dependency 'article'` in the `Comment` model, but I am looking for another way (maybe, better of the proposed one) to have the application to work as it is doing right now, but without any issue as-like that explained in this question. That is, I would like to keep a *short code** and the *same behavior* but using a more "appropriate" way to make things, maybe changing the loading process of classes or planning a big refactoring for the whole code, if necessary.

How should I handle this situation? What do you think about?

---

**Update**: After some study, I discovered that the problem arises only in development mode since the `config.cache_classes` is set to `false` making classes to be reloaded on every request.

---

*Note*: I want point out that metaprogramming is very usefull in my case and `Article` and `Comment` classes are highly related one to another in the aspect of *my* conception of "customization". So I would like to *find a solution alleviating changes to the underling behavior*.

---

* In my case, metaprogramming (even if it has side effects) makes me to avoid a lot of code statements.

Comment: Why don't you like `require_dependency` again? How is it "inappropriate"?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - It is mainly because: **(1)** I have *never seen* use that statement; **(2)** I'm *not sure* that is a "right" technique to solve the problem, mainly for future *maintenance* purposes; **(3)** Maybe, there are *other "appropriate" approaches* out there (as-like changing the loading process of classes or planning a big refactoring) in order to solve the issue.

Comment: It's exactly this: enforcing specific load order. So it **is** right tool for the job.

Comment: What I do not understand is how `act_as_customizable` is done on the `Article` and is supposed to add behaviour to `Comment`? I would make that explicit, e.g. why not call write `act_as_customizable` in `Comment`, then every time a `Comment` class is loaded, it will have the correct behaviour.

Comment: @nathanvda - "[...] why not call write `act_as_customizable` in `Comment`"? Given (as I wrote in the question) metaprogramming is very usefull in my case and `Article` and `Comment` classes are highly related one to another in the aspect of *my* conception of "customization", it is because I would like to keep a *short code*.

Comment: I find your answer a bit disrespectful. _Short code_ is no argument, and meta-programming is of course very useful. But clearly you are running into trouble, aren't you, so you are doing something wrong. Furthermore it is very hard to make any suggestions without seeing the code, could you show the relevant bits of the `Comment` and `Article` class, and the `act_as_customizable` implementation?

Comment: @nathanvda - The code that makes me trouble is an [`instance_exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) stated in the module related to the `acts_as_customizable` plugin of which the `Article` class makes use. It adds a `customize` method to the `Comment` class, nothing more. I don't know if that is "something wrong" when trying to take advantage from metaprogramming.

*P.S.*: Can you explain why you are finding my answer a bit disrespectful?

Comment: I was offended because you said nothing new, so you seemed unwilling to explain anything. What I ment with 'something wrong': obviously your `customize` is not defined all the time (because `Article` has to be loaded to define that method on `Comment`): for me that is wrong. Either you solve this in your code: split up the meta-programming in chunks, one method for `Article` and one for `Comment` (if you would show code I would gladly show how); but otherwise, without changing code, use `require_dependency` as mentioned before.

Comment: @nathanvda -  OK, I'd try to use the `require_dependency` method, but where can I find some example on using that (see also the first comment to *@Sergio Tulentsev*)?

*BTW*: After some study, I discovered that the problem arises only in development mode since the `config.cache_classes` is set to `false` making classes to be reloaded on every request.

*P.S.*: "I was offended because you said nothing new" ':-\